# Airflow 2: GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator gives Negsignal.SIGKILL

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

We're running airflow in google composer, and we're running into difficulties with the the GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator. We're using composer 2, and therefore I understand that we have to make sure to [use a connection with the correct scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817236/enable-google-drive-oauth-scopes-on-cloud-composer-2-0). So that's fine, I've set up a connection with those scopes, and we now no longer get permission errors. However, the dag still doesn't work, it now fails in a couple of different ways.

Most of the time, any dag that tries to upload a google sheet to GCS fails with error `Negsignal.SIGKILL`. For example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-10-03, 15:50:55 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1251} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-10-03, 15:50:55 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1252} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-10-03, 15:50:55 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1271} INFO - Executing <Task(GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator): upload_sheet_to_gcs_airflow_permission_test_sheet> on 2022-10-03 15:50:38.412899+00:00
[2022-10-03, 15:50:55 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 529848 to run task
[2022-10-03, 15:50:55 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'test_brunel_core_2', 'upload_sheet_to_gcs_airflow_permission_test_sheet', 'manual__2022-10-03T15:50:38.412899+00:00', '--job-id', '7342', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/DAGs/z_airflow_testing_dags/test_brunel_2_functions.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpyuhkixqc', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmp7p2delaz']
[2022-10-03, 15:50:55 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 7342: Subtask upload_sheet_to_gcs_airflow_permission_test_sheet
/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py:110: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/airflow/gcs/logs/test_brunel_core_2/upload_sheet_to_gcs_airflow_permission_test_sheet/2022-10-03T15:50:38.412899+00:00/1.log' mode='a' encoding='utf-8'>
  self.handler = NonCachingFileHandler(local_loc, encoding='utf-8')

[2022-10-03, 15:50:56 UTC] {task_command.py:298} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: test_brunel_core_2.upload_sheet_to_gcs_airflow_permission_test_sheet manual__2022-10-03T15:50:38.412899+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-j28mn
[2022-10-03, 15:50:56 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1448} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=process_dev_joe_m
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=test_brunel_core_2
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=upload_sheet_to_gcs_airflow_permission_test_sheet
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-10-03T15:50:38.412899+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-10-03T15:50:38.412899+00:00
[2022-10-03, 15:51:02 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL
[2022-10-03, 15:51:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1279} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=test_brunel_core_2, task_id=upload_sheet_to_gcs_airflow_permission_test_sheet, execution_date=20221003T155038, start_date=20221003T155055, end_date=20221003T155102
```

The rest of the time, some random task in the dag fails (not neccesarily the step with the GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator). Sometimes it a step fails with absolutely no log being generated at all, or sometimes log is generated but it contains no errors. Instead, the only clue is a warning:

```
/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py:110: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/airflow/gcs/logs/test_flakiness/create_table_JM_test_table.create/2022-10-04T09:11:58.425115+00:00/1.log' mode='a' encoding='utf-8'>
  self.handler = NonCachingFileHandler(local_loc, encoding='utf-8')
```

The weird thing about that warning is that it's warning about the log file itself. As in, that message is written into log file `gs://europe-west1-process-dev-ai-fd1dc540-bucket/logs/test_flakiness/create_table_JM_test_table.create/2022-10-04T09:11:58.425115+00:00/1.log`. So of course the file is open, you're writing to it, so why are you warning about it being open?

Some other facts that may or may not be relevant:

- `composer-2.0.25 airflow-2.2.5`
- When monitoring the environment, all
  resources (cpu, memory, etc) seem to be fine, nothing is hitting its
  limits.
- Our environment is configured to use between 1 and 4 workers.
  Only ever one worker is used, so I don't think it can be a problem
  with multiple workers all trying to write to the same file at once.
- This is all happening in our test environment. The same dag will work absolutely fine in our prod environment. Our
  prod environment is running `composer-1.19.3-airflow-2.2.5`, and
  therefore is set up differently when it comes to things like Google
  drive authentication scopes. So that's already 2 potential reasons
  why things are different in the prod environment.

Comment: You might check this SO post, this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231797/airflow-dag-fails-when-pythonoperator-with-error-negsignal-sigkill. If not, can you provide sample DAG, input file, etc. for me to reproduce your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution we found for the benefit of future generations.

We beefed up the environment size just in case that would help. And it turned out it totally fixed the problem! So we conclude that the monitoring dashboard in the GCP web interface is a bit misleading.

Perhaps Composer does some sort of throttling on the environment in order to prevent it hitting the cpu limits imposed by Composer? And thus Airflow crashes with SIGKILL, despite the cpu usage still *seemingly* being low?

Still feels a little bit mysterious, but tis good that we've managed to get it working.